# A more efficient or Pythonic way to implement a CSS deobfuscator?

Tags: python, html, css

I'm starting to learn some CSS and JavaScript. But sometimes, web pages have their CSS and JS code "obfuscated"; the code is difficult to read.

So, I made a simple script to "deobfuscate" the content of a CSS file (nothing complex), but I want to know if there is a more efficient or Pythonic way to implement the following code.

```
import fileinput
CSS_DEOBFUSCATE = {';': ';\n',
                   '{': ' {\n',
                   '}': '}\n',
                   ':': ': '}
for char_ in list(CSS_DEOBFUSCATE.keys()):
    for line in fileinput.input(file2deobfuscate, inplace=True):
        print(line.replace(char_, CSS_DEOBFUSCATE[char_]), end='')
```

Comment: You probably want to google _css pretty print_ or similar.

Comment: There are "beautify" tools that will do just this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because reviews of working code belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yeah, sure there are tools to "beautify", but i didn't make them... i'm just learning and wanting to do it myself. And things like "css pretty print" are new "terms" for me hehe, i search things like "deobfuscating css code with Python" or similar :P